# Load Different CSS Every Time a Page Loads

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to do something very similar to the JSFiddle found here, http://jsfiddle.net/Pp5up/ , where every time a page loads the background color changes.

The issue I am running into is that the example above changes the body's background.  I am trying to change the background color of a div every time a page loads.  I have tried for hours, but just can't seem to get it to work properly.  Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Pp5up/11/

**HTML**

```
<div id="nm-single-product-bg">
Test
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nm-single-product-bg.style1 {background:red;}
#nm-single-product-bg.style2 {background:blue;}
#nm-single-product-bg.style3 {background:black;}
```

**JS**

```
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
var style = "style" + rand;
document.getElementsById("nm-single-product-bg")[0].className+=style
```

If anyone can help, I would be so appreciative!

Comment: Side note, it's `getElementById` not `getElementsById`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/h6es01ur/. IDs are unique unlike classes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Wes Asbell! Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) You'll see what's causing the problem there.

Comment: @j08691 That's not a side note, it's the problem. That and the `[0]`.

Comment: Two issues: Change `getElementsById` to `getElementById`, and remove the `[0]`. Using `getElementById` will only return one element, and so you don't need to specify an index. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pp5up/12/ **EDIT:** Seems j08691 and Mike C have beat me to the punch! c:

Comment: check the working Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Pp5up/22/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
document.getElementsById("nm-single-product-bg")[0].className+=style
```

to this

```
document.getElementById("nm-single-product-bg").className+=style
```

The cause for this is already mentioned in comments :)

ID is unique for each element, so its `getElementById` instead of `getElementByIds` & since it always returns one unique div, no need for that array subscript.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pp5up/18/)